# Presto SQL window aggregate looking back x hours/minutes/seconds

Tags: sql, window, presto

I want to do aggregate on presto sql by looking back x hours/minutes/seconds ago.

Data

```
id    |       timestamp       |    status
-------------------------------------------
A     |   2018-01-01 03:00:00 |     GOOD
A     |   2018-01-01 04:00:00 |     BAD
A     |   2018-01-01 05:00:00 |     GOOD
A     |   2018-01-01 09:00:00 |     BAD
A     |   2018-01-01 09:15:00 |     BAD
A     |   2018-01-01 13:00:00 |     GOOD
A     |   2018-01-01 14:00:00 |     GOOD
B     |   2018-02-01 09:00:00 |     GOOD
B     |   2018-02-01 10:00:00 |     BAD
```

Results:

```
id    |       timestamp       |    status    | bad_status_count
----------------------------------------------------------------
A     |   2018-01-01 03:00:00 |     GOOD     |       0 
A     |   2018-01-01 04:00:00 |     BAD      |       1
A     |   2018-01-01 05:00:00 |     GOOD     |       1
A     |   2018-01-01 09:00:00 |     BAD      |       1
A     |   2018-01-01 09:15:00 |     BAD      |       2
A     |   2018-01-01 13:00:00 |     GOOD     |       0 
A     |   2018-01-01 14:00:00 |     GOOD     |       0
B     |   2018-02-01 09:00:00 |     GOOD     |       0
B     |   2018-02-01 10:00:00 |     BAD      |       1
```

I am counting bad status over the period of last 3 hours by business. How can I do that?
I am trying something like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  timestamp,
  status
  count(status) over(partition by id order by timestamp range between interval '3' hour and current_row) as bad_status_count
from table
```

Of course it doesnt work yet and I still have to filter out for bad status. I got this error:
 `Error running query: line 7:1: Window frame start value type must be INTEGER or BIGINT(actual interval day to second)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% how to represent express this in PrestoDB, but the key idea is to convert the timestamps to hours:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when status = 'Bad' then 1 else 0 end) over
           (partition by id
            order by hours
            range between -3 and current row
           ) as bad_status
from (select t.*,
             date_diff(hour, '2000-01-01', timestamp) as hours
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: and we want to shorten the time period by minutes and seconds, we just put `date_diff(minute, '2000-01-01', timestamp)` or `date_diff(second, '2000-01-01', timestamp)` respectively.

Comment: @addicted . . . If this works for hours, then changing the time period will work for other units of time.

Comment: the date_diff works but the range between -3 and current row doesn't work for me. There is an error (`mismatched input 'row'. Expecting: '%', '*', '+', '-', '.', '/', 'AT', '[', '||', <expression>). Seems like this is not the input to expect

Comment: @addicted . . . Change the `current row` to `0 following` as you originally had it.  Perhaps that is needed for the `range` window specification.