# Is there a window function to compute average spending per merchant the last 90 days in Presto?

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I want to compute the average spending per merchant the last 90 days.
I have been doing that with pyspark SQL:

```py
df_spark = df_spark.withColumn("t_unix", F.unix_timestamp(df_spark['date']))

windowSpec = Window.orderBy("t_unix").partitionBy("merchant").rangeBetween(-3 * 30 * 24 * 3600, -1)
average_spending = F.avg(df_spark['amount']).over(windowSpec)

df = df_spark.withColumn("average_spending", average_spending)

df.select('merchant', 'date', "amount", "average_spending").show(5)

+---------+-------------------+-------+----------------+
| merchant|date               |amount |average_spending|
+---------+-------------------+-------+----------------+
| 26      |2017-01-01 01:11:06|  3    |            null|
| 26      |2017-01-01 02:02:15| 54    |             3.0|
| 26      |2017-01-01 02:26:45|  6    |            28.5|
| 26      |2017-01-01 02:40:37|  4    |            21.0|
| 26      |2017-01-01 02:41:51| 85    |           16.75|
+---------+-------------------+-------+----------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

And now **I want to do it in AWS Athena (Presto)**.

I tried the query below:

But I got the error message:

```
Your query has the following error(s):

SYNTAX_ERROR: line 7:24: Unexpected parameters (varchar(3), integer, varchar) for function date_add. Expected: date_add(varchar(x), bigint, date) , date_add(varchar(x), bigint, time) , date_add(varchar(x), bigint, time with time zone) , date_add(varchar(x), bigint, timestamp) , date_add(varchar(x), bigint, timestamp with time zone)
```

But in date_add('day', -90, "date") I want "date" as the current timestamp of the row and not a static timestamp.

```sql
SELECT
   "date",
   "merchant",
   "amount",
   AVG("amount") 
   FROM "table"
   WHERE ("date" BETWEEN date_add('day', -90, "date") and "date")
   GROUP BY "merchant"
   ORDER BY "date"
   LIMIT 5
```

But I got the error message:

```
Your query has the following error(s):

SYNTAX_ERROR: line 7:24: Unexpected parameters (varchar(3), integer, varchar) for function date_add. Expected: date_add(varchar(x), bigint, date) , date_add(varchar(x), bigint, time) , date_add(varchar(x), bigint, time with time zone) , date_add(varchar(x), bigint, timestamp) , date_add(varchar(x), bigint, timestamp with time zone)
```

But in **date_add('day', -90, "date")** I want "date" as **the current timestamp of the row** and **not a static timestamp**.

I did another attempt with:

```sql
SELECT
   unix_date,
   merchant,
   amount,
   AVG(amount)
      OVER 
      (  PARTITION BY merchant
         ORDER BY unix_date
         RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '90' DAY PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
      ) AVG_S
FROM ...;
```

But I got the error message:

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 5:4: Window frame start value type must be INTEGER or BIGINT(actual interval day to second)
```

There is a similar unsolved issue here:
[Presto SQL window aggregate looking back x hours/minutes/seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54233225/presto-sql-window-aggregate-looking-back-x-hours-minutes-seconds)

Comment: What do you mean by "current timestamp of the row"? Have a look at `from_unixtime` function (https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#from_unixtime). Does it help?

Comment: I am trying to find the function with which I can calculate at any point in time what was the average spending for the last 90 days. A recurring/rolling average for the last 90 days but when I use the above I get an error. Fox example, if I have a list of all the days in a year, I need to be calculating the average of the last 90 days for every day.

Comment: Do you have data point for each merchant and day, or is it sparse? What's the type of `date` column?

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen yes data point for each merchant and day, and the type of date column is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been working for me.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS full_year_query_parquet
  WITH (format = 'PARQUET',
        parquet_compression = 'SNAPPY',
        external_location='s3://your_s3_bucket/data') AS
SELECT
    a.merchant,
    a.amount,
    a.date,
    avg(preceding.amount)
  FROM "your_table" as a
  JOIN "your_table" as preceding ON a.merchant = preceding.merchant
    AND preceding.date > DATE_ADD('day', -90, a.date)
    AND preceding.date < a.date
  GROUP BY a.merchant, a.amount, a.date
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have one data point for each merchant×date, this can be done easily using [Presto's window functions](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/window.html)

```
SELECT
  date, merchant, amount,
  avg(amount) OVER (
    PARTITION BY merchant
    ORDER BY date ASC
    ROWS 89 PRECEDING) -- 89 preceding rows + the current row
  FROM ...
  ORDER BY date ASC -- not necessary, but you likely want the data to be sorted as well
```

If you have varying number of data points for each merchant and date, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
  c.merchant, c.date, c.amount, avg(preceding.amount)
  FROM your_table c
  JOIN your_table preceding ON c.merchant = preceding.merchant
    AND preceding.date BETWEEN (c.date - INTERVAL '89' DAY) AND c.date
  GROUP BY c.merchant, c.date, c.amount
```

Comment: Yes but this is not what I want. I do not want 89 rows preceding but 89 days. I tried with `RANGE BETWEEN` but I got the error **Window frame RANGE PRECEDING is only supported with UNBOUNDED**:

Comment: Since you have a data point for each merchant and day, 89 preceding rows is the same as 89 preceding days.

Comment: My bad, I have several transactions per day for each merchant. So I can have multiple rows with the same day and hence 89 preceding rows is **not** the same as 89 preceding days . I put a table example above.

Comment: Presto does not support bounded range frames -- as opposed to row frames (https://github.com/prestosql/presto/blob/b3315f21f53d6f4fbfa82f03fb159c563dd9bd5d/presto-main/src/main/java/io/prestosql/sql/analyzer/StatementAnalyzer.java#L1474-L1478). If you have unspecified number of data points per day, I would use self-join with inequality filter (i extended my answer with proposed approach)